# Emitting unencoded strings in a Razor view

Tags: asp.net, razor, html-encode

As ScottGu says in his blog [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx) «by default content emitted using a @ block is automatically HTML encoded to better protect against XSS attack scenarios».
My question is: how can you output a non-HTML-encoded string?

For the sake of simplicity, pls stick to this simple case:

```
@{
 var html = "<a href='#'>Click me</a>"
 // I want to emit the previous string as pure HTML code...
}
```

Answer (score 115, accepted):

This is my favorite approach:

```
@Html.Raw("<p>my paragraph text</p>")
```

Source was Phil Haack's Razor syntax reference: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx

Answer (score 17):

You can create a new instance of MvcHtmlString which won't get HTML encoded.

```
@{
  var html = MvcHtmlString.Create("<a href='#'>Click me</a>")
}
```

Hopefully there will be an easier way in the future of Razor.

If you're not using MVC, you can try this:

```
@{
  var html = new HtmlString("<a href='#'>Click me</a>")
}
```

Comment: Actually you sould be able to use `new HtmlString()` in MVC 3 as well since that type is .NET 4.

Comment: Indeed! However when typing all that in one expression I like the MVC one more. E.g. @MvcHtmlString.Create(myString). Personal preference!

Answer (score 6):

new HtmlString is definitely the answer.

We looked into some other razor syntax changes, but ultimately none of them ended up really being any shorter than new HtmlString.

We may, however, wrap that up into a helper.  Possibly...

```
@Html.Literal("<p>something</p>")
```

or

```
@"<p>something</p>".AsHtml()
```

Comment: Would it be possible to add @=myString as a way to output HTML? Maybe too much of a flashback to WebForms...

Comment: We want to avoid adding syntax constructs where they don't cover a major user case.  Most of the time, you'll be using helper methods to build strings and IHtmlString works perfectly there.  For the odd cases where you need to output a literal string without a helper, we can provide a method for you: @Literal(foo) or similar.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and Razor under Mono.

I couldn't get HtmlHelper from System.Web.WebPages of System.Web.Mvc for some reasons.

But I managed to output unencoded string after declaring model's property as `RazorEngine.Text.RawString`. Now it outputs as expected.

Example

```
@{
    var txt = new RawString("some text with \"quotes\"");
    var txt2 = "some text with \"quotes\"";
}
<div>Here is unencoded text: @txt</div>
<div>Here is encoded text: @txt2</div>
```

Output:

```
<div>Here is unencoded text: some text with "quotes"</div>
<div>Here is encoded text: some text with &quot;quotes&quot;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well when transitioning our project to the new Razor view engine. The approach I took was slightly different because we had to generate JSON data from C# and wanted to output it upon page load.

What I eventually did was to implement a RawView that was a parallel of View inside of the cshtml files. Essentially, to get a raw string,

```
@(new HtmlString(View.Foo))

// became
@RawView.Foo
```

This requires a few changes to the project layout, so I just wrote up a blog post about it [here](http://www.akngo.com/blog/html-unencoding-for-razor-view-engine-on-asp-net-mvc-3/). In short, this required a duplicate implementation of MVC's DynamicViewDataDictionary and a new WebViewPage that contains the RawView. I also went ahead and implemented the index operator on the RawView to allow for

```
@RawView["Foo"]
```

In the off-chance that someone needs to loop over the data with a list of keys.

Reading anurse's comment, it probably would have been better off if I had named this as a Literal instead of RawView.