# How to display string and prevent encoding HTML tags

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Emitting unencoded strings in a Razor view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356790/emitting-unencoded-strings-in-a-razor-view)

I have a string that has HTML tags such as:

```
string = "hi<br/>bye";
```

I want to be able to output this in my C# ASP.NET MVC3 (Razor) view such that the `<br/>` tags are preserved and not encoded. I know encoding is happening automatically to prevent cross-site scripting.

What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Are you talking about ASP.NET MVC or WebForms?

Comment: I was actually pretty convinced that ASP.NET didn't encode this and that you had to do it yourself...

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET MVC3 with Razor views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `@Html.Raw`.